# Devise login straight with github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth

Im using devise for user registration and have a link which redirects to the login page.

```
<%= link_to "User Sign in", new_user_session_path, :class => "btn btn-default navbar-btn" %>
```

Iv set up omniauth using the following [tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/ruby-on-rails/tutorial/rails-omniauth-with-devise--github-example).

The `link_to` I'm using above takes me to the devise `sign_in` page where I then have to click on `sign in with github` which then redirects me login with github.

I would rather skip the `sign-up` page and once I click on the above `link_to` I want it to go straight to the github authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out, I changed the `link_to` to:

```
<%= link_to user_github_omniauth_authorize_path %>
```

Comment: Ah! I was close :) where did you find the Solution?

Comment: found it here and changed it to use github instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26484157/devise-twitter-omniauth-get-user-email

Comment: It seems it proposes the same solution i gave

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to use the following `link_to` helper in any view of your app:

```
<%= link_to "Sign in with GitHub", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:github) %>
```

You can find more info about devise-omniauth integration [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview).

Comment: this does not work undefined method `user_omniauth_authorize_path'

Comment: can you pls run `rake routes` and update your answer with all the routes that you get?

Comment: or even easier: can you access the sign_in view and check the code that generate the `sign in with github` link? You should be able to use same link everywhere in your app ...